# Equivalent to /*.txt of bash in python

Tags: python, bash

In bash there is `${files_path}/*.txt` that takes all the .txt files in the specific path. Is there an equivalent script in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`glob` is exactly what you're looking for.

> The **glob** module finds all the pathnames matching a specified pattern according to the rules used by the Unix shell, although results are returned in arbitrary order. No tilde expansion is done, but *, ?, and character ranges expressed with [] will be correctly matched.

Using `glob` module:

```
>>> import os, glob
>>> os.listdir('.')
['package', 'test.py', 'test.pyc', 'test2.py', 'test2.pyc']
>>> glob.glob('*.pyc')
['test.pyc', 'test2.pyc']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Import os
- List all files in the directory
- Filter all files that end with "txt"

So something like this:

```
import os
txt_files = list(filter(lambda x: x.endswith(".txt"), os.listdir(<yourpathhere>)))
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use the package os

```
import os
PATH = "GIVE PATH HERE"
print os.listdir(PATH)
```